# Getting Mono context when using Mono.fromCallable

Tags: project-reactor

We use a WebFilter to add an object to the `Mono.subscriberContext`. This object contains trace-ids passed in via HTTP headers.

```
chain.filter(exchange)
    .subscriberContext(Context.of(SomeClass.class, contextObject))
```

We then use the following code to Wrap legacy JDBC calls in Mono :

```
Mono.fromCallable(() -> legacyDao.jdbcCall(contextObject)))
            .timeout(Duration.ofMillis(timeout))
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic());
```

I am trying to access the `Mono.subscriberContext` to retrieve the object containing the trace-ids. This will then be used in the DAO call to add the trace-ids to MDC when logging.

Normally we use `doOnEach(signal -> ...)` to get the object from the context and do the logging.

I know Spring Sleuth is an option, but we would prefer not to use it at this stage.

Comment: I'm not sure which context you try to get. You need to provide the surrounding code.

Comment: your solution of flatMapping from `Mono.subscriberContext()` is correct, you should add that as a self answer

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67421363/334569)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Simon Baslé pointed out, the solution is to wrap with `Mono.subscriberContext`

```
Mono.subscriberContext().flatMap(context -> {
    ContextObject contextObject = context.get(SomeClass.class);
    return Mono.fromCallable(() -> legacyDao.jdbcCall(contextObject))
            .timeout(Duration.ofMillis(timeout))
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic());
});
```