# How to correctly use slf4j MDC in spring-webflux WebFilter

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I referenced with the blog post [Contextual Logging with Reactor Context and MDC](https://simonbasle.github.io/2018/02/contextual-logging-with-reactor-context-and-mdc/) but I don't know how to access reactor context in WebFilter.

```
@Component
public class RequestIdFilter implements WebFilter {

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
        List<String> myHeader =  exchange.getRequest().getHeaders().get("X-My-Header");

        if (myHeader != null && !myHeader.isEmpty()) {
            MDC.put("myHeader", myHeader.get(0));
        }

        return chain.filter(exchange);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## 2023: Forget `logOnNext` wrapper. Use Context Propagation

I started working with Reactor back in 2018, and thus far, there hasn't been a truly good alternative to the wrapper method inside `doOnNext` where you manually copy your trace fields from Reactor's Context into MDC, making your own ad-hoc bridge between reactive and imperative worlds, and voilà, your logs now could make sense. But things changed, and finally, a new solution is here – [Context propagation](https://spring.io/blog/2023/03/30/context-propagation-with-project-reactor-3-unified-bridging-between-reactive). Let's take a look at it.

Imagine that you have your Spring service, and you have a set of fields that define your diagnostic context, the fields you use for tracing the service's activities. Let's assume that you store that set as the following property: `management.tracing.baggage.correlation.fields: trace, session`.

Now, to have these fields automatically populated into the MDC of the thread that executes the call of your reactive chain, sourcing the keys-values from the reactive context, you just need to add [context-propagation](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/context-propagation#artifacts) library to your project and after do the following service-wide configuration:

```java
/**
 * 1. Will register ThreadLocalAccessors into ContextRegistry for fields listed in application.yml as property value
 * <b>management.tracing.baggage.correlation.fields</b>
 * 2. Enables Automatic Context Propagation for all reactive methods
 *
 * @see <a href="https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/context-propagation">context-propagation</a>
 */
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnClass({ContextRegistry.class, ContextSnapshotFactory.class})
@ConditionalOnProperty(value = "management.tracing.baggage.correlation.fields", matchIfMissing = true)
public class MdcContextPropagationConfiguration {

    public MdcContextPropagationConfiguration(@Value("${management.tracing.baggage.correlation.fields}")
                                              List<String> fields) {
        if (!isEmpty(fields)) {
            fields.forEach(claim -> ContextRegistry.getInstance()
                                                   .registerThreadLocalAccessor(claim,
                                                                                () -> MDC.get(claim),
                                                                                value -> MDC.put(claim, value),
                                                                                () -> MDC.remove(claim)));
            return;
        }

        Hooks.enableAutomaticContextPropagation();
    }
}
```

The trick here is to use `Hooks.enableAutomaticContextPropagation()`. As soon as we register a set of ThreadLocalsAccessors for propagation that maps out the tracing fields, the hook will ensure the passing on of the values under the keys of the registered fields from the reactive context into MDC *on each call of your chain*. These fields within MDC subsequently could be referenced in slf4j appenders in any preference.

That's it.

Answer (score 15):

**December 2023 edit**: this solution may be deprecated (did not verify myself as I am not using Webflux anymore), see the solution linked in a comment by @SerhiiPovísenko.

Original answer:

Here's one solution based on the latest approach, as of *May 2021*, taken from the [official documentation](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/blob/main/docs/asciidoc/faq.adoc#what-is-a-good-pattern-for-contextual-logging-mdc):

```java
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.slf4j.MDC;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpRequest;
import org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebExchange;
import org.springframework.web.server.WebFilter;
import org.springframework.web.server.WebFilterChain;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;
import reactor.core.publisher.Signal;
import reactor.util.context.Context;

@Slf4j
@Configuration
public class RequestIdFilter implements WebFilter {

  @Override
  public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
    ServerHttpRequest request = exchange.getRequest();
    String requestId = getRequestId(request.getHeaders());
    return chain
        .filter(exchange)
        .doOnEach(logOnEach(r -> log.info("{} {}", request.getMethod(), request.getURI())))
        .contextWrite(Context.of("CONTEXT_KEY", requestId));
  }

  private String getRequestId(HttpHeaders headers) {
    List<String> requestIdHeaders = headers.get("X-Request-ID");
    return requestIdHeaders == null || requestIdHeaders.isEmpty()
        ? UUID.randomUUID().toString()
        : requestIdHeaders.get(0);
  }

  public static <T> Consumer<Signal<T>> logOnEach(Consumer<T> logStatement) {
    return signal -> {
      String contextValue = signal.getContextView().get("CONTEXT_KEY");
      try (MDC.MDCCloseable cMdc = MDC.putCloseable("MDC_KEY", contextValue)) {
        logStatement.accept(signal.get());
      }
    };
  }

  public static <T> Consumer<Signal<T>> logOnNext(Consumer<T> logStatement) {
    return signal -> {
      if (!signal.isOnNext()) return;
      String contextValue = signal.getContextView().get("CONTEXT_KEY");
      try (MDC.MDCCloseable cMdc = MDC.putCloseable("MDC_KEY", contextValue)) {
        logStatement.accept(signal.get());
      }
    };
  }
}
```

Given you have the following line in your `application.properties`:

```
logging.pattern.level=[%X{MDC_KEY}] %5p
```

then every time an endpoint is called your server logs will contain a log like this:

```
2021-05-06 17:07:41.852 [60b38305-7005-4a05-bac7-ab2636e74d94]  INFO 20158 --- [or-http-epoll-6] my.package.RequestIdFilter    : GET http://localhost:12345/my-endpoint/444444/
```

Every time you want to log manually something within a reactive context you will have add the following to your reactive chain:

```
.doOnEach(logOnNext(r -> log.info("Something")))
```

If you want the `X-Request-ID` to be propagated to other services for distributed tracing, you need to read it from the reactive context (not from MDC) and wrap your `WebClient` code with the following:

```
Mono.deferContextual(
    ctx -> {
      RequestHeadersSpec<?> request = webClient.get().uri(uri);
      request = request.header("X-Request-ID", ctx.get("CONTEXT_KEY"));
      // The rest of your request logic...
    });
```

Comment: so is the MDC actually being used? can we just simply use the UUID and pass it through the reactive chain, or is there something else i'm missing?

Comment: What's the practical difference between `logOnEach()` and `logOnNext()` - to dynamically change the content in the latest?

Comment: in logs its not reflecting, is this solution works still?

Comment: that solution is deprecated. Use Context Propagation instead, see the example here https://stackoverflow.com/a/77418615/2852528

Answer (score 10):

As of Spring Boot 2.2 there is Schedulers.onScheduleHook that enables you to handle MDC:

```
Schedulers.onScheduleHook("mdc", runnable -> {
    Map<String, String> map = MDC.getCopyOfContextMap();
    return () -> {
        if (map != null) {
            MDC.setContextMap(map);
        }
        try {
            runnable.run();
        } finally {
            MDC.clear();
        }
    };
});
```

Alternatively, Hooks.onEachOperator can be used to pass around the MDC values via subscriber context.

http://ttddyy.github.io/mdc-with-webclient-in-webmvc/

This is not full MDC solution, e.g. in my case I cannot cleanup MDC values in R2DBC threads.

UPDATE: this article really solves my MDC problem: https://www.novatec-gmbh.de/en/blog/how-can-the-mdc-context-be-used-in-the-reactive-spring-applications/

It provides correct way of updating MDC based on subscriber context.

Combine it with `SecurityContext::class.java` key populated by `AuthenticationWebFilter` and you will be able to put user login to your logs.

Comment: Where do you put `Schedulers.onScheduleHook`?

Comment: You can just use `@PostConstruct ` of a Spring config class. The approach in the article works for me. Not sure about performance impact, though, but I think it should be fine.

Comment: unfortunately https://www.novatec-gmbh.de/en/blog/how-can-the-mdc-context-be-used-in-the-reactive-spring-applications/ isn't available anymore

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20210710020142/https://www.novatec-gmbh.de/en/blog/how-can-the-mdc-context-be-used-in-the-reactive-spring-applications/

Answer (score 9):

You can do something similar to below, You can set the `context` with any class you like, for this example I just used headers - but a custom class will do just fine. 
If you set it here, then any logging with handlers etc will also have access to the `context`.
The `logWithContext` below, sets the MDC and clears it after. Obviously this can be replaced with anything you like.

```
public class RequestIdFilter  implements WebFilter {

    private Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RequestIdFilter.class);

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
        HttpHeaders headers = exchange.getRequest().getHeaders();
        return chain.filter(exchange)
                .doAfterSuccessOrError((r, t) -> logWithContext(headers, httpHeaders -> LOG.info("Some message with MDC set")))
                .subscriberContext(Context.of(HttpHeaders.class, headers));
    }

    static void logWithContext(HttpHeaders headers, Consumer<HttpHeaders> logAction) {
        try {
            headers.forEach((name, values) -> MDC.put(name, values.get(0)));
            logAction.accept(headers);
        } finally {
            headers.keySet().forEach(MDC::remove);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: you'd need to invert the `.subscriberContext` and `.doAfterSuccessOrError` though , because the context writes are only visible to operators above it

Comment: if we want to set the context for the entire application, how can we do it?

Comment: @SimonBaslé, I am using reactor's .log(). MDC data is lost there when events are logged using .log(). Anyway to cleanly get MDC there?

Comment: nope. you have to understand MDC is just not a silver bullet anymore in a world where several distinct processing can occur on the same thread

Comment: MDC.put is static and uses an static object inside to store the values. Wouldn't this be a problem?

Answer (score 1):

##### My solution based on [Reactor 3 Reference Guide approach](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#faq.mdc) but using doOnSuccess instead of doOnEach.

**The main idea** is to use [Context](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/util/context/Context.html) for MDC propagation in the next way:

1. Fill a downstream Context (which will be used by derived threads) with the MDC state from an upstream flow (can be done by `.contextWrite(context -> Context.of(MDC.getCopyOfContextMap()))`)
2. Access the downstream Context in derived threads and fill MDC in derived thread with values from the downstream Context (*the main challenge*)
3. Clear the MDC in the downstream Context (can be done by `.doFinally(signalType -> MDC.clear())`)

The main problem is to access a downstream Context in derived threads. And you can implement step 2 with the most convenient for you approach). But here is my solution:

```java
webclient.post()
   .bodyValue(someRequestData)
   .retrieve()
   .bodyToMono(String.class)
// By this action we wrap our response with a new Mono and also 
// in parallel fill MDC with values from a downstream Context because
// we have an access to it
   .flatMap(wrapWithFilledMDC())
   .doOnSuccess(response -> someActionWhichRequiresFilledMdc(response)))
// Fill a downstream context with the current MDC state
   .contextWrite(context -> Context.of(MDC.getCopyOfContextMap())) 
// Allows us to clear MDC from derived threads
   .doFinally(signalType -> MDC.clear())
   .block();
```

```java
// Function which implements second step from the above main idea
public static <T> Function<T, Mono<T>> wrapWithFilledMDC() {
// Using deferContextual we have an access to downstream Context, so
// we can just fill MDC in derived threads with 
// values from the downstream Context
   return item -> Mono.deferContextual(contextView -> {
// Function for filling MDC with Context values 
// (you can apply your action)
      fillMdcWithContextView(contextView);
      return Mono.just(item);
   });
}
```

```java
public static void fillMdcWithContextValues(ContextView contextView) {
   contextView.forEach(
      (key, value) -> {
          if (key instanceof String keyStr && value instanceof String valueStr) {
             MDC.put(keyStr, valueStr);
          }
   });
}
```

This approach is also can be applied to doOnError and onErrorResume methods since the main idea is the same.

Used versions:

- spring-boot: 2.7.3
- spring-webflux: 5.3.22 (from spring-boot)
- reactor-core: 3.4.22 (from spring-webflux)
- reactor-netty: 1.0.22 (from spring-webflux)

Answer (score 0):

In addendum to the ContextRegistry solution listed above, I recommend the following instead of registering each individual field:

```
ContextRegistry.getInstance().registerThreadLocalAccessor("MDC", MDC::getCopyOfContextMap, MDC::setContextMap, MDC::clear);
```

That seems better than having to pass in each possible field name. This would erase other values in the new reactor thread MDC if there were any, though I've yet to experience that happening.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

I achieved this with :-

```
package com.nks.app.filter;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.slf4j.MDC;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebExchange;
import org.springframework.web.server.WebFilter;
import org.springframework.web.server.WebFilterChain;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

/**
 * @author nks
 */
@Component
@Slf4j
public class SessionIDFilter implements WebFilter {
    
    private static final String APP_SESSION_ID = "app-session-id";
    
    /**
     * Process the Web request and (optionally) delegate to the next
     * {@code WebFilter} through the given {@link WebFilterChain}.
     *
     * @param serverWebExchange the current server exchange
     * @param webFilterChain    provides a way to delegate to the next filter
     * @return {@code Mono<Void>} to indicate when request processing is complete
     */
    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange serverWebExchange, WebFilterChain webFilterChain) {
        serverWebExchange.getResponse()
                .getHeaders().add(APP_SESSION_ID, serverWebExchange.getRequest().getHeaders().getFirst(APP_SESSION_ID));
        MDC.put(APP_SESSION_ID, serverWebExchange.getRequest().getHeaders().getFirst(APP_SESSION_ID));
        log.info("[{}] : Inside filter of SessionIDFilter, ADDED app-session-id in MDC Logs", MDC.get(APP_SESSION_ID));
        return webFilterChain.filter(serverWebExchange);
    }
}
```

and, values associated with `app-session-id` for the thread can be logged.

Comment: This is not correct - when your Mono scheduled on another thread (e.g. after database query) MDC will not be set for that thread. Also, there is no proper cleanup of MDC in your code.

Comment: I just want to highlight an important problem in your solution: straight-forward MDC usage in WebFlux reactive code leads to incorrect logging, that's why there are solutions that use different Reactor hooks to achieve correct behavior.