# How can I log every request that is coming to my Webflux application without breaking my reactive capabilities?

Tags: spring, spring-webflux, project-reactor

Log every request that is coming to my application .Which is the best place to put the filter so that it is not blocking for my application.

Comment: It seems you have to use either AOP or Filter with block way. Because how you want to log something without event happend may be some exception occured etc

Comment: Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51738140/how-to-correctly-use-slf4j-mdc-in-spring-webflux-webfilter