# Log request id with SLF4J MDC in Spring webflux with coroutines

Tags: kotlin, spring-webflux, slf4j, kotlin-coroutines, mdc

I am trying to log the request id and other properties like request path from requests to the Spring webflux endpoint with RouterFunctions. The issue is when I put in the MDC information it gets lost at some point for example when making a database request with R2DBC. I was wondering what a possible solution was since none of the solutions I was able to find worked. Below is some of the code that I am using for my project:

RouterFunction code:

```
fun routes(
    testResource: TestResource,
    errorResource: ErrorResource
): RouterFunction<ServerResponse> = coRouter {
    filter(::filterMDC)
    filter(::filterException)
    "api".nest {
        "/v1/test/{test}".nest {
            GET("", testResource::test)
        }
    }
}
```

filterMDC code:

```
suspend fun filterMDC(request: ServerRequest, next: suspend (ServerRequest) -> ServerResponse): ServerResponse {
MDC.put(
    REQUEST_ID_MDC_PARAM,
    request.headers().firstHeader(REQUEST_ID_HEADER_NAME) ?: UUID.randomUUID().toString()
)

....

MDC.put(
    RESOURCE_MDC_PARAM,
    "${request.methodName()} ${request.uri()}"
)
return next(request)
}
```

testResource test code:

```
suspend fun test(
    serverRequest: ServerRequest
): ServerResponse {
    logger.info(
        "foo" to "bar"
    ) { "foobar" }

    val user = withContext(MDCContext()) {
        testRepository.getUser()
    }

    return ServerResponse.ok().bodyValueAndAwait(user.let(::toApiResponse))
}
```

TestRepository code:

```
class TestRepository(
    private val r2dbcEntityTemplate: R2dbcEntityTemplate
) {
    suspend fun getUser(): User {
        return r2dbcEntityTemplate
            .select<User>()
            .from("users")
            .awaitOne()
    }
}
```

I have tried to use MDCContext from SLF4J for coroutines but that didn't solve the issue with the MDC context being lost. Is there a good way to solve this?

Comment: MDC does not work, as it uses threadlocal which cannot be used in webflux. You need to use the reactive context. There is a chapter on it in the reactor documentation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to correctly use slf4j MDC in spring-webflux WebFilter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51738140/how-to-correctly-use-slf4j-mdc-in-spring-webflux-webfilter)

Answer (score 0):

Two ways I've found to get this to work are (1) with `coRouter` and (2) with `CoWebFilter`. **NOTE**: this appears to work *only* when this filter is the *last* to run so that the actual request handler is called within the coroutine with the MDC context. This means using `@Order(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)` for the CoWebFilter. For the filter in `coRouter`, lowest precedence seems to be the default

1. `coRouter`

```
import io.github.oshai.kotlinlogging.KotlinLogging
import io.github.oshai.kotlinlogging.withLoggingContext
import kotlinx.coroutines.slf4j.MDCContext
import kotlinx.coroutines.withContext

@Bean
fun mainRouter() = coRouter {
    POST("/test", {
        ServerResponse.ok().buildAndAwait()
    })
    filter { serverRequest, next ->
        withLoggingContext("correlationId" to "something") {
            withContext(coroutineContext + MDCContext()) {
                next(serverRequest)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

2. `CoWebFilter`

```
import org.springframework.web.server.CoWebFilter
import io.github.oshai.kotlinlogging.KotlinLogging
import io.github.oshai.kotlinlogging.withLoggingContext
import kotlinx.coroutines.slf4j.MDCContext
import kotlinx.coroutines.withContext


@Configuration
@Order(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)
class CoroutineRequestContextFilter : CoWebFilter() {
    companion object {
        private val logger = KotlinLogging.logger {  }
    }

    override suspend fun filter(exchange: ServerWebExchange, chain: CoWebFilterChain) {
        withLoggingContext("correlationId" to (exchange.request.headers["requestId"]?.firstOrNull() ?: "requestIdNotProvided")) {
            withContext(MDCContext()) {
                logger.info { "in withContext of filter" }
                chain.filter(exchange)
            }
        }
    }
}
```