# Spring WebFlux - WebFilter add name from Authentication to MDC

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, spring-webflux, mdc

I have a Spring boot WebFlux application.
I have to add name hidden in Authentication object into MDC so all the logs can be enhanced with it.

My code looks like this:

Controller:

```java
@RestController
class MobileController {

  @PostMapping("/")
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
  public Mono<Response> initializePayment(BearerTokenAuthentication authentication, Request request) {
    String userId = String.valueOf(authentication.getTokenAttributes().get("username"));

    log.info("[initializePayment] Initializing payment process for user: {}, with request: {}",
            userId, request);
    // my logic here
```

WebFilter:

```java
@Component
class LogFilter implements WebFilter {
    
  @Override
  public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
    return ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext()
        .doOnNext((sc) -> {
          if (sc.getAuthentication() != null) {
            MDC.put("user_id", sc.getAuthentication().getName());
          }
        })
        .then(chain.filter(exchange));
  }
```

But with this code I only have `"user_id"` logged in in some "parallel threads" - not in the reactor one, see the logs below::

```
{"thread_name":"reactor-http-nio-3","message":"[fdedf164-1] HTTP POST "/api/v1/"}
{"thread_name":"reactor-http-nio-3","message":"[6501f595] HTTP POST https://server-host/oauth/token/introspect"}
{"thread_name":"reactor-http-nio-3","message":"[6501f595] Writing form fields [token] (content masked)"}
{"thread_name":"reactor-http-nio-3","message":"[6501f595] [705ad9f1-1, Response 200 OK"}
{"thread_name":"reactor-http-nio-3","message":"[6501f595] [705ad9f1-1,  Decoded [{active=true, scope=USER, client_id=0d46cc1c-3062-11e9-8c56-3b7c3075f9de, username=ada5bc12-4518-419 (truncated)...]"}
{"thread_name":"parallel-1","message":"Created new WebSession."}
{"user_id":"ada5bc12-4518-4199-80ee-111111222222","thread_name":"parallel-1","message":"[fdedf164-1] Mapped to )"}
{"user_id":"ada5bc12-4518-4199-80ee-111111222222","thread_name":"parallel-1","message":"[fdedf164-1] Content-Type:application/json"}
{"user_id":"ada5bc12-4518-4199-80ee-111111222222","thread_name":"parallel-1","message":"[fdedf164-1] 0..1 []"}
{"thread_name":"reactor-http-nio-3","message":"[fdedf164-1] Decoded "}
```

I have also tried adding `MDC.put()` in the controller and then I get `"user_id"` in each log but only after the controller has been reached, meaning that I will be unable to match the incoming server call with the user.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to correctly use slf4j MDC in spring-webflux WebFilter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51738140/how-to-correctly-use-slf4j-mdc-in-spring-webflux-webfilter)

Comment: I've seen above. There is no answear to my question.

Comment: There is an answer to your question, you need to store it in the context and when logging copy it to the MDC (which should by in a try-with-resources block). Else it won't work as the MDC is a ThreadLocal and in a reactive pipeline there might be multiple threads and thus you need to copy it around.

Comment: OK, so it will work but only for logs specified explicitly by me in the code in the chain. I assume there is no option to do that for all logs like Jackson encoder, WebHandlerAdapter etc. In the non-reactive world it is enough to place MDC.put("") in the filter and it gets to any logs which is really what I am after.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/Numichi/reactive-logger library that solves the problem with MDC in WebFlux applications.

The following snippet stores the username to MDC so you can log it. It gets executed right after the user is authenticated, so there are cases when the username is not yet set in logs, or when there is no user interaction, therefore a meaningful default value in your logging pattern might be a good idea, e.g. `[%boldYellow(%X{username:-SYSTEM})]`.

```kotlin
import io.github.numichi.reactive.logger.reactor.MDCContext.modify
import org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.filter.OrderedWebFilter
import org.springframework.security.config.web.server.SecurityWebFiltersOrder.AUTHENTICATION
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication
import org.springframework.security.core.context.ReactiveSecurityContextHolder
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component
import org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebExchange
import org.springframework.web.server.WebFilterChain
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono
import reactor.util.context.Context

@Component
class UsernameMdcWebFilter : OrderedWebFilter {

    override fun getOrder() = AUTHENTICATION.order + 1

    override fun filter(
        exchange: ServerWebExchange,
        chain: WebFilterChain
    ): Mono<Void> = ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext()
        .mapNotNull { it.authentication }
        .flatMap { authentication ->
            chain.filter(exchange)
                .contextWrite { addUsernameToMdc(it, authentication) }
        }

    private fun addUsernameToMdc(
        context: Context,
        authentication: Authentication
    ) = modify(context, "username" to authentication.user)
}
```

Once you introduce this mechanism, you must make sure that you use an appropriate logger from the library, which serves as an adapter that extends standard logging libraries like LOG4J or KLogger. To do this, create your Logger using `io.github.numichi.reactive.logger.LoggerFactory`, which has a similar usage as `org.slf4j.LoggerFactory`.

Comment: LoggerFactory is just one helper class and it gives native Logger or Klogger and doesn't use wrapper in reactive environment. I recommend use one of Coroutine(K)Logger or Reactore(K)Logger.