# Springboot reactive (Webclient) contextual logging for propagating MDC

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux

As per this article (http://ttddyy.github.io/mdc-with-webclient-in-webmvc/) to pass MDC variables across reactive chain, we need to add two things:

a) ExchangeFilterFunction (a webclient filter that copies MDC context)

b) Schedulers.onScheduleHook (a hook that also copies MDC context)

```
ExchangeFilterFunction function = (request, next) -> {
      // here runs on main(request's) thread
      Map<String, String> map = MDC.getCopyOfContextMap();
      return next.exchange(request)
              .doOnNext(value -> {
                // here runs on reactor's thread
                if (map != null) {
                  MDC.setContextMap(map);
                }
              });
    };
    
WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder().filter(function).build();

Schedulers.onScheduleHook("mdc", runnable -> {
  Map<String, String> map = MDC.getCopyOfContextMap();
  return () -> {
      if (map != null) {
        MDC.setContextMap(map);
      }
      try {
        runnable.run();
      } finally {
        MDC.clear();
      }
  };
});
```

Same solution is mentioned in [How to correctly use slf4j MDC in spring-webflux WebFilter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51738140/how-to-correctly-use-slf4j-mdc-in-spring-webflux-webfilter/69076401#69076401)

Why do we need to add Schedulers.onScheduleHook, for me context is getting propagated just by adding a webclient filter? what will i miss if i don't add  context propagation in Schedulers.onScheduleHook?

Comment: IF you don't and ther eis code in the chain that does `scheduleOn` or `schedule` you will loose the context. However you shouldn't really need any of this with newer Spring Boot versions (3+).

Comment: @M.Deinum: Thanks for your reply. Do you have any reference documentation how it can be done in spring boot 3+ version without any of above?

Comment: That is automatically applied when micrometer is detected (at least it should). Which is also explained right at the top of the blog you linked to (it has some gist to configure additional propagation).

Answer (score 1):

Sharing for others if anyone else facing issues in implementing contextual logging using WebClient.

In springboot3 adding micrometer automatically propagates tracing headers without any need of adding schedulerHook. However, we still need to add filters in WebClient for logging request & response along with tracing headers.

Below is the complete solution in springboot3 & WebClient for logging request & response with body and contextual logging:

```
//Add following libraries compatible with springboot3 version:
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'io.micrometer:micrometer-observation'
    implementation 'io.micrometer:micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave' 

//Add traceId & spanId in logging pattern:
    logging.pattern.level= "%5p [${spring.application.name:},%X{traceId:-},%X{spanId:-}]"
```

Create webclient bean from builder. Make sure WebClient builder is spring injected then only it will decorate request calls with trace header

```
            @Bean
            WebClient webClient(WebClient.Builder builder) {
                try {
                    //Adding trust all certificate for bypassing ssl
                    SslContext sslContext = SslContextBuilder
                            .forClient()
                            .trustManager(InsecureTrustManagerFactory.INSTANCE)
                            .build();
                    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create().secure(t -> t.sslContext(sslContext));
        
                    //Adding LoggingClientHttpConnector for logging request body as filter doesn't log body
                    ClientHttpConnector clientHttpConnector =
                            new LoggingClientHttpConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient));

                    //Cloning builder for Thread safety
                    WebClient.Builder clonedBuilder = builder.clone();
                    clonedBuilder.clientConnector(clientHttpConnector);

//Adding filters in cloned filter for logging & copy MDC                    
return clonedBuilder .baseUrl("https://catfact.ninja/fact").filter(logRequest()).filter(logResponse()).filter(copyMDCMap()).build();
                } catch (SSLException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
        
            }
```

Below code is for adding filter for logging request & response contents in WebClient:

```
/**
 * This is for logging request url & header, for body use LoggingClientHttpConnector
 * @return
 */
public static ExchangeFilterFunction logRequest() {
    return ExchangeFilterFunction.ofRequestProcessor(request -> {

        LOG.info("Request URL is {} for method {}",request.url(), request.method());
        logHeaders(request.headers(), "Request");
        return Mono.just(request);
    });
}


/**
 * This is for logging response url, header and body
 * @return
 */
public static ExchangeFilterFunction logResponse() {
    return ExchangeFilterFunction.ofResponseProcessor(response -> {
        LOG.info("Response status code is {}", response.statusCode());
        logHeaders(response.headers().asHttpHeaders(), "Response");
        //For logging body needs to access response and mutate it
        return Mono.just(
                response.mutate()
                        .body(dataBuffer -> dataBuffer.map(dataBuffer1 -> {
                            LOG.info("Response body is {}",dataBuffer1.toString(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                            return dataBuffer1;
                        }))
                        .build());
    });
}


private static void logHeaders(HttpHeaders httpHeaders, String type) {
    LOG.info("{} Headers are {}",type, httpHeaders);
}

/**
 * This is for copying MDC context across webclient chain
 * @return
 */
public static ExchangeFilterFunction copyMDCMap() {
    return (request, next) -> {
        Map<String, String> map = MDC.getCopyOfContextMap();
        return next.exchange(request)
                .doOnNext(value -> {
                    // here runs on reactor's thread
                    if (map != null) {
                        MDC.setContextMap(map);
                    }
                });
    };
}
```

And lastly, below code for logging request body, as webclient doesn't give access to it so had to log it at the connector level:

```
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.client.reactive.ClientHttpConnector;
import org.springframework.http.client.reactive.ClientHttpRequest;
import org.springframework.http.client.reactive.ClientHttpResponse;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

import java.net.URI;
import java.util.function.Function;

public class LoggingClientHttpConnector implements ClientHttpConnector {

    private final ClientHttpConnector delegate;

    public LoggingClientHttpConnector(ClientHttpConnector delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<ClientHttpResponse> connect(HttpMethod method, URI uri,
                                            Function<? super ClientHttpRequest, Mono<Void>> callback) {

        return this.delegate.connect(method, uri,
                request -> callback.apply(new LoggingClientHttpRequestDecorator(request)));
    }
}

import org.reactivestreams.Publisher;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DataBuffer;
import org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DataBufferUtils;
import org.springframework.http.client.reactive.ClientHttpRequest;
import org.springframework.http.client.reactive.ClientHttpRequestDecorator;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class LoggingClientHttpRequestDecorator extends ClientHttpRequestDecorator {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggingClientHttpRequestDecorator.class);
    public LoggingClientHttpRequestDecorator(ClientHttpRequest delegate) {
        super(delegate);
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> writeWith(Publisher<? extends DataBuffer> body) {
        // optionally aggregate for full body content
        body = DataBufferUtils.join(body)
                .doOnNext(content -> {
                    LOG.info("Request body is {}",content.toString(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                });
        return super.writeWith(body);
    }
}
```